# CSS align after expanding navbar

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me to align the search bar beside my icon? This is how it currently looks like.

Before expanding :

> [image]

After expanding :

> [image]

I want to have my search bar beside my image after expanding, can someone help me out here? Thanks!

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.hehe {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: skyblue;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .topnav a:not(:nth-child(-n+2)),
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a:not(:nth-child(-n+2)),
  .hehe {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .hehe {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .hehe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" ng-controller="searchController">
          <a href="#!/index" class="searchba"><img ng-src="" />LOGO</a>
          <input type="text" class="searchFeature" ng-model="selected" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && searchFunction()" uib-typeahead="value for value in themename | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:7" placeholder="Start your search here...">
        <div class="hehe">
          <a href="">Developer</a>
          <a href="">Data Enquiry</a>
        </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Categories <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content" >
              <a ng-click="pickCate(x)" ng-repeat="x in selectCate">{{ x }}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hello - I've put the code you posted into a stack snippet exactly as you wrote it, but as you can see, it does behave as described in the post.  Can you please edit the snippet in your question so it demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Updated @billynoah

Comment: that's better but we still can't see your image.  since that's an important element and you want to align things with it, can you please edit your code to include an image link that works?  also, not to be nit-picky but please stop adding long rows of dots in your post.

Comment: I can't save my edits. It says too much code thats why I am adding the dots x:

Comment: maybe you should post about that on meta - i've never heard of SO saying "too much code" or preventing you from saving a post

Comment: I get this message "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.". I updated it with a LOGO btw. Thanks!

Comment: I've never encountered that warning before - asked about it on meta just now if you want to follow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376667/op-cant-edit-post-without-adding-meaningless-dots-due-to-mostly-code-warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding, `position: relative;` to the nav, and an absolute for `.searchFeature`

```
.topnav{
  position: relative;
}

.searchFeature{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 65px;
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/gQWwjR) you have a codepen!

Comment: It stays beside now but it mess up the other content

Comment: Yep, now that you added the Js I can see it

Comment: Just edited the answer, let me know if that new solution help you